# How to handle Finuploader s3 signature failure {invalid: true}

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Cannot handle s3 signature failure in fineuploader. It returns {invalid:true} but cannot find a way to handle this.

I want to show custom message on signature failure.

Answer (score 0):

In your [`onComplete` handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete), check the passed `responseJson` parameter. You will find that the `success` property on the object is set to `true`, and the `error` property contains an appropriate error message. I realize that it may also be beneficial to include the `invalid` property from your signature server response. Please do open up a pull request to add this and I will be happy to help push this through.

Comment: onComplete called only after the s3 successful upload and not after signature verification.

Comment: It will be called after the upload fails. The upload will fail if your signature endpoint returns `{invalid: true}`.

Comment: I have checked with onComplete, onError and few others but no success

Comment: There there is some other issue with your environment or code.